# Symfony error trying to create an Admin Bundle class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to use the SonataAdminBundle to get some backend admin functions up and running but have hit a roadblock with my first config class.

I have added the following to app/config/config.yml

```
services:
    sonata.admin.sport:
        class: Clarity\CoachTimeBundle\Admin\SportAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: General, label: Sports}
        arguments: [null, Clarity\CoachTimeBundle\Entity\Sport, null]
```

And have the following class defined in the path src/Clarity/CoachTimeBundle/Admin/SportAdmin.php

```
<?
namespace Clarity\CoachTimeBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class SportAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name');
    }

    public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
    {
        $errorElement
            ->with('name')
                ->assertMaxLength(array('limit' => 255))
            ->end();
    }
}
```

When I try to clear cache and run the application I get the following error:
  The autoloader expected class "Clarity\CoachTimeBundle\Admin\SportAdmin" to be defined in file "src//Clarity/CoachTimeBundle/Admin/SportAdmin.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Shot in the dark, but does your php.ini allow the `<?` tag (the `short_open_tag` directive)? If not, then changing `<?` to `<?php` might work...

Comment: Also, you've got a missing semicolon in your configureDatagridFilters() method. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Downside of working from home is you have no one to look over your shoulder and point out the stupid mistake. Thanks tomtheman! The problem was indeed the short open tag!

Comment: Sounds like you're in need of a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)